# MassTransit consumed on single server

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

I am struggling to configure MassTransit with RabbitMQ to publish messages and subscribe to the queue. I think that its a simple configuration change that needs to be done. I have multiple services connected but the messages get consumed alternatively and never gets delivered / consumed on the other server.

I would like each message to get delivered to every connection / subscriber.

I am running this on ASP.net core 6 on the latest version of MassTransit.

```
 services.TryAddSingleton(KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);
        services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
   {
       cfg.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(c =>
       {
            c.Host(connectionString, c =>
            {
                c.Heartbeat(10);
            });
            c.ConfigureEndpoints(
                 context, 
                 KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);

            c.Publish<VideoManagerResultEvent>(x =>
            {
                x.BindQueue("result", "video-msgs");
                x.ExchangeType = Fanout;
            });

            c.ReceiveEndpoint("result:video-msgs", e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<VideoManagerResultConsumer>();
            });
        }));

        // Request clients / DTO
        RegisterRequestClients(cfg);
    });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
  }




 private static void RegisterRequestClients(IServiceCollectionBusConfigurator cfg)
 {
    cfg.AddRequestClient<VideoManagerResultEvent>();
 }




 // consumer
 public class VideoManagerResultConsumer : BaseConsumer<VideoManagerResultEvent>
 {
      public override async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<VideoManagerResultEvent> context)
     {
         Logger.Debug("Consumed video event");
         await context.RespondAsync(new GenericResponse());
      }
 }
```

I call "SendMessage()" to publish a message to RabbitMQ.

```
// constructor and DI
public EventBusV2(IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
{
    _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
}

public async Task SendMessage()
{
    await _publishEndpoint.Publish<VideoManagerResultEvent>(msg);
}
```

To add to the original question the diagram display what is currently happening.

Diagram 1 - The request or message gets published to the eventbus but only gets delivered to the one instance of the consumer.

Diagram 2 - The required result the message gets published to both instances of the consumer.

[image]

The RaabitMQ Queue

[image]

Comment: You might start with a [simple getting started](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/#with-rabbitmq) to understand how MassTransit configures RabbitMQ. The fact that you're customizing exchanges, etc. seems to indicate that you're off track and into the weeds. You configuration is general is really broken as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only configuration you should need is the following:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddConsumer<VideoManagerResultConsumer>()
        .Endpoint(e => e.InstanceId = "Web1"); // or 2, etc.

    cfg.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    cfg.UsingRabbitMq((context, c) =>
    {
        c.Host(connectionString, c =>
        {
            c.Heartbeat(10);
        });

        c.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });

    // Request clients / DTO
    RegisterRequestClients(cfg);
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Any published messages of type `VideoManagerResultEvent` will end up on the queue `video-manager-result` based upon the consumer name.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I started off with following the Mass-Transit documentation. I was using IRequestClient<VideoManagerResultEvent> to initialise a request, this is when I started having the exact problems and ending up thinking i need to follow a sub/pub pattern. FYI - should I be calling IPublishEndpoint.Publish<VideoManagerResultEvent> ?

Comment: Also the above doesn't look to register any consumers?

Comment: I updated it to add the consumer, I didn't realize you hadn't.

Comment: I tried the above and get exactly the same issue regarding that the message / request is delivered to only one consumer. I will add a diagram to the original questions - Btw really appreciate your time answering the questions

Comment: Updated, if you want to fan out, you need to specify a unique InstanceId when adding the consumer.

Comment: Would generating this at runtime cause any problems in the future? For example generating a GUID for the instance ID?

Comment: Well, the endpoint isn't temporary in this example. If it can be a temporary endpoint, add `e.Temporary = true` as well, and sure you can use a Guid. I mean, it can be anything, but if you're generating a Guid each time you start the service, you're creating a lot of soon-to-be-orphaned queues. Which is why I brought up temporary.

Comment: Brilliant makes perfect sense. Now to get this working on Azure service bus :)